# Flexbox - two small items next to one large

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to have a layout that looks like this on mobile

```
-----
| 1 |
-----
| 2 |
-----
| 3 |
-----
```

And like this on desktop:

```
---------
|   | 1 |
| 2 |---|
|   | 3 |
|   |----
|   |
-----
```

I decided to use flexbox, my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl secound">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm first">1<br>2<br>3<br>4</div>
  <div class="col-xl third">3</div>
</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col-sm,
.col-xl {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-sm {
  background: yellow;
}

.col-xl {  
  &.secound {
    background: #ccc;
  }

  &.third {
    background: #aaa;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
.col-sm {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
}

.col-xl {
  width: 75%;

  &.secound {
    background: #ccc;
    order: 2;
  }

  &.third {
    background: #aaa;
    order: 3;
  }
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't *slide* column "3" under "1". What should I do?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/PbprJP?editors=1100

Comment: the height of `1` is dynamic?

Comment: Yes it is, @kukkuz

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `float` for desktop, and using flexbox with `order` set for mobile.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp7rgh1g/)**

```css
.item-1 {background:aqua;}
.item-2 {background:gold;}
.item-3 {background:pink;}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
}
.item-2 {
  float: left;
}
.item-1,
.item-3 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  .item-1 {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item-2">2<br><br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could align `.third` on the right by using flex property `justify-content`.

You're CSS would look something like this:

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row > div{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

For changing order you can use the `order` property:

```
.first{  order: 1; }
.second{ order: 2; }
.third{  order: 3; }

@media (min-width: 700px){
  .first{  order: 2; }
  .second{ order: 1; }
  .third{  order: 3; }
}
```

[Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/fuaymvar/)

On [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can find a great guide for using Flex properties.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution doesn't work, please make a fiddle/codepen.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: added fiddle

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I just saw the edit you made to your question. That changes things quite a bit. You probably should wrap `cell 1` and `cell 2` together in a separate "flexbox", but that's going to make it impossible to change the order of cells without using JS or something.

Comment: not sure why, but even if height of "2" should be combined of both 1 and 3, it still doesn't fit.

Comment: That's because it arranges it's "cells" into "rows". You could think of it as a table in which you can't merge cells. Cells will never overlap to another row. You can fake this behavior by adding new "rows" into "cells". But that's kind of overkill and not what you'd typically want in a clean flexible layout. You can also check CSS Grids, that's kinda been made for this stuff: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

There are few things I've given sizes too just for the sake of the demo but it will still work without the sizes.

You will need to give your container a size but that can be 100vh/100vw or even percentage rather than actual pixels.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.item-1 {
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00bcd5;
}
.item-2 {
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #8bc24a;
}
.item-3 {
  line-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fec107;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .item-1,
  .item-2,
  .item-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item-1,
  .item-3 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .item-2 {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, but I cannot set a height on `.container`, since I don't know how much content there will be.

Comment: In order for flexbox to know it needs to wrap into another column, I think you need a height

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float: right` for all three elements instead. Together with the appropriate width definitions in media queries, this should work.

Comment: I thought about it, and - if I'll find no other way - I'll just throw `float`s in there, but I'd really love to stay with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Grid:

```css
/* Column */
.item {
  width: 100%; 
}

/* Wrap */
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}


/* Responsive */
@media screen and (min-width: 700px){
  .row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  .item { width: 50%;}
  
  .item-1 { order: 2; }
  .item-2 { order: 1; }
  .item-3 { order: 3; }
}


/* Custom style */
.item {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 3rem;  
}

.item-1 {
  background: #00bcd5;
}

.item-2 {
  background:#8bc24a;
}

.item-3 {
  background:#fec107;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
</div>
```

grid with hook:

```css
/* Column */
.item {
  width: 100%; 
}

/* Wrap */
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.sub-row {
  display: none;
}

.item-1 { order: 1; }

.item-2 { order: 2; }

.item-3 { order: 3; }


/* Responsive */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
  .row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  .sub-row {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  
  .sub-row .item { width: 100%;}
  
  .item { width: 50%;}
  
  .hidden { display: none; }
  
  .item-2 { order: 1; }
  
  .sub-row  { order: 2; }
  
}


/* Custom style */
.item {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 3rem;  
}

.item-1 {
  background: #00bcd5;
}

.item-2 {
  background:#8bc24a;
}

.item-3 {
  background:#fec107;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">  
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="sub-row">
    <div class="item item-1">1</div>
    <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="item hidden item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item hidden item-3">3</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Elements can't have fixed heights. Please look at my "sketch".

Answer (score 0):

How about using absolute position?

In your media query change the `.row` class to this:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

And your `.item-2` to:

```
  .item-2 { order: 1; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

```css
/* Column */
.item {
  width: 100%; 
}

/* Wrap */
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}


/* Responsive */
@media screen and (min-width: 700px){
  .row {
    position: relative;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  
  .item { width: 50%;}
  
  .item-1 { order: 2; }
  .item-2 { order: 1; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
  .item-3 { order: 3; }
}


/* Custom style */
.item {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 3rem;  
}

.item-1 {
  background: #00bcd5;
}

.item-2 {
  background:#8bc24a;
}

.item-3 {
  background:#fec107;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2
    <br>2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
</div>
```

---

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wojrrd?editors=1100)